# How to get rid of gas from mead?

Tags: bottling, mead, co2

I have brewed 5L of mead (1 part honey to 3 parts water). After 9 months I can no longer see any sedimentation in the bottle, however when I taste the mead I can feel it's a little sparkling (besides that it tastes okay). Does it mean, that the mead is still immature or will the gas leave when I put the mead in room temperature? (it now stands in a cellar with temperature several centigrades below room temperature).

So what should I do? Wait a little more or is it safe to bottle the mead now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a degasser, just like for wine.  Also works great to aerate beer...

[image: Mix Stir degasser]

Comment: Damn - i did a lookup about these tools and I see how to use it (connecting it to a drill). However I can't find one in any polish e-shop. Could I use a manual stirrer? How long should I stir then?

Comment: To degas, stir til it doesn't foam any more.  You could also use something like a whisk or paint mixer, depending if it would fit in your fermenter.

Answer (score 4):

The [wine wand](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/wine-wand.html) or the [mix/stir](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/mix-stir-stainless-steel.html) works well for degassing but you should be adding sulphites or campdem tablets before this process to absorb the oxygen and prevent oxidaton.

Another great way to degas is to use a pump.  Blichmann engineering has the [WineEasy vacuum degassing kit](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/winemaking/wine-equipment/wine-fermenting-equipment/blichmann-wineeasy/wineeasy-vacuum-degassing-kit.html) that works very well.  This is a much larger investment but will not introduce oxygen into the mead or wine you are degassing.  This product should only be used with glass carboys as plastic ones will crumple under the pressure.